# Get shortcode attribute value to another function

Tags: functions, shortcode

I am trying to get shortcode attribute value to another function to add inline style.I want to use `$color`'s value to another function.

Here is my code

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class MakeShortcode
{

    public $color;
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'init', array($this, 'PostBLock') );
        add_shortcode( 'PostBLock', array($this, 'getpostblock') );

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'inlinestyle') );

    }

    public function getpostblock( $atts ){
        extract( shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'section_color' => '#000000',

        ), $atts) );

        $this->color = $section_color;

        $output = 'First LIne';
        $output .= 'Second Line';
        return $output;
    }
    public function inlinestyle(){
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'custom-style',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css'
        );
        $custom_css = "
            div[data-id=289374].post-block-post-left.active,
            div[data-id=289374].post-block-post-right.active{
                background : {$this->color};
                border-color : {$this->color};
            }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
    }
}
$test = new MakeShortcode();
```

But `background` and `border-color` becomes empty.That means i am not getting `$this->color` value in that function.How i can get that?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` is called before the shortocode render. then if you want to choose a custom color in a page, add a meta box to select the color in the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class MakeShortcode
{

public $color;
public function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'PostBLock') );
    add_shortcode( 'PostBLock', array($this, 'getpostblock') );

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'inlinestyle') );

}

public function getpostblock( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( 
    array(
        'section_color' => '#000000',

    ), $atts) );

    return $section_color;
}
public function inlinestyle(){
 $color = $this->getpostblock();  
 wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css'
    );
    $custom_css = "
        div[data-id=289374].post-block-post-left.active,
        div[data-id=289374].post-block-post-right.active{
            background : {$color};
            border-color : {$color};
        }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
}
$test = new MakeShortcode();
```

Comment: But i have something to return on `getpostblock()` .check the question now it would be something like That

Comment: in your inlinestyle() function you can use $this->getpostblock()->$color

Comment: But not works.Here are some error:
`Warning: Missing argument 1 for MakeShortcode::getpostblock()`
`Notice: Undefined variable: atts`
`Notice: Undefined variable: color`
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: what is your initial errror?...is WP_DEBUG set to true?

Comment: Yes it was turned on .now i turned false..but not working .. $color is not echoing yet.. here is complete file what i am working with : https://pastebin.com/5ctWCgbu
it is actually a visual composer shortcode

Comment: did you add this line #819 :- $color = $this->prinz_v_ps_sm()->$color;

Comment: yes after your comment :)

Comment: and $color on #826 and #827 also??...i dont see any $color defined above

Comment: yes..but where to define?

Comment: try $section_color and remove.... $color = $this->prinz_v_ps_sm()->$color;

Comment: Ye s tried `$color = $this->prinz_v_ps_sm()->$section_color;` removing `$color = $this->prinz_v_ps_sm()->$color;`
but still not works

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: after line 60 add $this->sectioncolor = $section_color and on line 819 replace $this->prinz_v_ps_sm()->$color; with $this->sectioncolor

Comment: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for PrinzPostHorizontalMinimal::prinz_v_ps_sm()` `Notice: Undefined variable: atts` `Notice: Undefined variable: color` `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: No no warning or notices but not working : https://pastebin.com/zvahHrDg

Comment: any idea? @Piyush Rawat

Comment: Nopes... can't figure it out...will look into it...onto my way home from office